# Are there performance benefits to receiving a application/json Content-Type over JSON.parse'ing a text/plain string?

Tags: networking

(Server agnostic question, but I am interested if it differs depending on the server software.)

I was recently told that we needed to change back end requests from `JSON.stringify(object)` with a content type of `text/plain` to just `object` with a content type of `application/json`. I am all for this due to technical correctness of identifying the data.

However, the reasoning was that this would provide performance benefits by alleviating the need to `JSON.parse` the string that is received.

It is my understanding that no matter what content type you send, it is still a *string* being received by the server. In the world of 0's and 1's of data transmission, there is no distinction between a JSON object and a string. I believe that when the server receives a Content-Type application/json, it just calls `JSON.parse` before passing the data to your application -- meaning there is no *performance* benefit to using one over the other, because they are doing the same thing.

Is my interpretation correct, or is the server somehow able to handle one content type faster than the other?

Comment: There's probably no performance benefit, but sending JSON with a `text/plain` content type is what we call a code smell.

Answer (score 4):

On the contrary, I see a reason for using `text/plain` !

If you are using CORS (cross origin request) and using `application/json` then the request will no longer be considered "simple request" and then the browser will issue a pre-flight request (using http OPTIONS) to check the CORS is allowed.

Using `text/plain` will enable CORS without the pre-flight request, making the response return faster.

Answer (score 1):

For a well written application, no, it shouldn't matter in terms of performance, especially considering that automatic deserialization of JSON should be doing exactly the same thing as the default behavior of manually deserializing it.  It does kind of matter in terms of correctness though (JSON is not plain text, so you shouldn't be using `text/plain` as the content type).

That said, there is one case I can think of where it *might* matter.  If you have a firewall that does deep packet inspection and tries some from of antivirus scanning on the content, and both the firewall and the AV software blindly trust the content type, it *might* be more efficient to send the data s `text/plain`.  The likelihood of all of those criteria being met is essentially nil however, so you shouldn't code for it.

Comment: I'm just curious, for my edification, in what way is JSON not plain text?

Comment: @EBGreen It's structured data and it may contain byte values not considered by the local system to be 'plain text'.